# Message Consumption using Kafka Consumer - Java

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I saw the below code for consuming messages from Kafka. There is 1 topic with 20 partitions and 20 threads are created using ExecutorService. There are 20 message streams each reading from 1 partition. When this program is run , 20 messages will be read and will be processed from topic. When 1 one of these threads complete the processing , I assume the next message will be read.

If in a example scenario where 100 messages are in topic , will all the messages be read and kept in memory and will 20 be processed at a time by the threads or will the message be read from the topic only after the messages currently being processed by the thread are processed?

```
public void run(int a_numThreads) {
    Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(a_numThreads));
    Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
    List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);

    // now launch all the threads
    //
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

    // now create an object to consume the messages
    //
    int threadNumber = 0;
    for (final KafkaStream stream : streams) {
        executor.submit(new ConsumerTest(stream, threadNumber));
        threadNumber++;
    }
}
```

EDIT : I came across the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646699/can-consumer-groups-span-different-nodes-in-a-cluster). However I have the below questions :

If there are 20 partitions for a single topic , can I run the consumer on 2 different nodes? Should i mentioned the number of message streams as 10 in each of  those consumers? When I node fails or if there is a performance issue , will the stream of data automatically re-balance to the working node?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run more than 1 consumer on different nodes to consume from same topic. Number of message stream can be 10 of different based on machine configuration. If its tiny machine you can give 5 or so.

If one node fails it automatically transfers to load to other node. Other than the failure there are other properties like topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms which decides when to re-balance to load.

Comment: Thanks Paresh. If there are 20 partitions , can I set 20 partitions each on both the nodes? If one fails , I guess all the 20 partitions will be processed by 20 threads in a single consumer.

Comment: Partitions are specified when you have created topic. If there is 1 broker in your configuration   all 20 partitions are in one broker. If you have 2 brokers, partitions are distributed. You don't need to specify the number of partitions at consumer level. So to answer your this question "If one fails , I guess all the 20 partitions will be processed by 20 threads in a single consumer" , Yes if one fails all the partitions moves to one node and processed by single consumer.

Comment: Sorry , I was not clear with my question. Assuming there are 2 nodes in my cluster and 20 partitions. I assume 20 partitions will be distributed across 2 nodes and the traffic will re-balance itself. I have a consumer project which creates 20 message streams and processes the data using 20 threads. If I deploy the same application in 2 nodes , will 10 partitions be processed by 1 instance consumer application and will other 10 be processed by the other instance.

Comment: Is there any way, where new message will be read from the kafka topic only after the messages currently being in process by the thread got processed